# Cómo pasar datos de una página a otra en NextJs?

Tags: nextjs, next

Tengo una aplicación de un carrito en Next con 2 páginas, una es un Login y la otra el Main con los productos y sus categorías. En el Login obtengo la dirección, cómo podría pasar ese valor a la página de Main para mostrarlo y poder trabajar con ese dato?

Comment: No sé mucho de esto pero creo que no deberías intentar pasar datos directamente de una parte del frontend a otra. Sino que el backend sea intermediario. Si crees que no debería pasar por el backend, supongo que puedes pasar la información por la URL, cookies o alguna otra forma.

Answer (score 0):

hay varias formas en las que podrías pasar los datos del login a la página principal en una aplicación de Next.js:

Usando cookies: Una forma de pasar datos entre páginas es a través de cookies. Cuando el usuario inicia sesión, podrías crear una cookie que contenga la dirección del usuario y que se guarde en el navegador del cliente. Luego, en la página principal, podrías leer la cookie y utilizar el valor para mostrar la dirección del usuario.

Usando localStorage: Otra forma de pasar datos entre páginas es a través de localStorage. Cuando el usuario inicia sesión, podrías guardar la dirección del usuario en localStorage. Luego, en la página principal, podrías leer el valor de localStorage y utilizarlo para mostrar la dirección del usuario.

Usando props: Si la página principal es una página de Next.js, podrías pasar los datos del login como props a la página principal. Para hacer esto, necesitarías utilizar la función getServerSideProps en la página principal y obtener los datos del login desde el servidor. Luego, podrías pasar los datos como props a la página principal y utilizarlos para mostrar la dirección del usuario.

aca te doy un ejemplo practico:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default function Main({ direccion }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Tu dirección es: {direccion}</h1>
      {/* Aquí mostrarías los productos y categorías */}
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { direccion } = context.query;

  // Aquí podrías hacer una llamada a la API o a una base de datos para obtener más información sobre el usuario, si es necesario.

  return {
    props: {
      direccion,
    },
  };
}
```

En este ejemplo, he utilizado la función 'getServerSideProps' para obtener los datos del login desde el objeto context. Luego, he pasado los datos como props a la página principal y los he utilizado para mostrar la dirección del usuario.

Pone mas informacion igual, la pregunta hecha esta mal, se necesita informacion precisa. corres el riesgo de que te cierren la pregunta.